# Faster RCNN for multi-channel images with Tensorflow Object Detection API (or others)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

I would like to implement a Faster RCNN architecture for multichannel images (5 channels) but a YOLO is much the same for me if it is more straighforward

I am starting with the Tensorflow Object Detection API:

1. Is it possible easily or it requires a deep rewriting of the architecture?
2. which would be the best strategy?
3. which files should I change?

I don't have a particular preference between TF, PyTorch, etc. so if anybody have advice/tips for other libraries, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in Tensorflow Object Detection API:

Mainly for preparing the input you need to change the format of your **.tfrecord** file to store a multi-dimensional array by preparing your inputs as a numpy array and encode it as string-like below-mentioned code example:

```
# Read your image and extra inputs
image = cv2.imread('path/to/image')[:, :, ::-1]
background = cv2.imread('path/to/background')[:, :, ::-1]
# Image and background are numpy arrays that has dimension of H x W x 3
# Concatenate them on depth channel to create an H x W x 6 input
inputs_stacked = np.concatenate([image, background], axis=-1)
# Encode your input as string
encoded_inputs = inputs_stacked.tostring()
```

For the architecture code and other details you can refer this [link](https://github.com/minhnhat93/tf_object_detection_multi_channels).

Hope this helps you. Happy Learning!

Comment: @scaramouche88 - Please upvote and accept the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.